# Как обновить изображение на canvas, отрисованном через Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, fetch

Ситуация очень хитрая для меня и, возможно, заголовок не отражает сути, простите, я просто не разбираюсь в js.

Понадобилось мне сделать рендер скина игрока Minecraft, ну и нашел я js-библиотеку skinview3d.
Как я понял, она использует библиотеку Three, тут без вопросов.

Модельку со скином я отрисовал и все работает:

```
let skinViewer = new skinview3d.SkinViewer({
        domElement: document.getElementById("skin"),
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        skinUrl: 'URL'
    });
```

Далее мне нужно обновить скин на сервере, это я делаю отправкой формы с файлом через fetch, назад получаю новый url со скином (это png файл).

В skinViewer можно указать этот новый url так:

```
skinViewer.skinUrl = url;
```

Но это не обновляет уже отрисованный canvas с моделькой игрока, а skinViewer не содержит никаких методов для этого. Чтобы все перерисовалось, приходится перезагружать страницу, но это не подходит.

Как мне все же перерисовать этот canvas без перезагрузки страницы?

А ну и ссылка на [skinview3d](https://github.com/bs-community/skinview3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась главным образом в том, что у меня изображение кешировалось браузером (путь меняется редко).
Костыльное решение: добавлять к url случайный параметр вроде `?rand=58388`.
Ну а перерисовку canvas делаю его удалением через `skinViewer.dispose();` и новым добавлением.